# How to correctly use tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer() for synchronous distributed training?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed, synchronous

#### Files to reproduce:

[training.py](https://gist.github.com/GD06/b88d4b20a4587add984323525bbf4be2): This file contains the source code for the parameter server and workers created to use synchronous distributed optimizers (tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer) and training supervisors.
[run.sh](https://gist.github.com/GD06/0bdb36ba6b76070b7cd7fadfd30fce6b): This file launched the parameter server and the workers.

#### Problem description

Recently, I tried to deploy the synchronous distributed TensorFlow training on the cluster. I followed the tutorial and the inception example to write my own program. The training.py follows the same API usage as the official example. I enabled it running on a single machine with multiple GPUs by making them communicate through localhost and mapping each worker to see only one GPU.

The run.sh launched three processes. One of them is the parameter server and the others are two workers implemented by between-graph replication. I created the training supervisor by tf.train.Supervisor() to manage multiple sessions in the distributed training for the initialization and synchronization.

I expect these two workers would synchronize each batch and work in the same epoch. However, the worker 0, which is launched prior to the worker 1, completed the whole training set without waiting for the worker 1. After that, the process of the worker 0 finished training process and exited normally while worker 1 behaved like falling into the deadlock and keep near 0% utilization of CPU and GPU for several hours.

Based on my observation, I suspect these two workers didn't communicate and synchronize at all for the data they passed. I report this problem as a bug because I create the optimizer tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer as suggested by the official website and the inception example. However, it seems that the synchronization behaviors, if any, are very strange and the program can not exit normally.

#### A GitHub issue or a Stack Overflow question?

I created an issue [#9596](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9596) for the TensorFlow because I used neither the optimizer nor the training supervisor inappropriately. However, this issue has been closed because the official team didn't think this is a bug. Is there anyone helping me figure out what is wrong with my code and the correct method to use tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(). If none of you think I call the optimizer incorrectly, I will consider to propose it as an issue again very soon.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I further edit the [training.py](https://gist.github.com/GD06/b56d62b718bbd0b033703320e4b214dc) to make worker 1 exist after the first time output information. Then the worker 0 continue to execute without waiting for the worker 1. This behavior makes me convince that these two workers run asynchronously. I update it also in the GitHub issue [#9596](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9596). For others who may concern, you can follow this issue also.

Comment: Probably bit too late for an answer but anyway: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11753